# pgplot does not work

Tags: linux

I installed pgplot 5.2 successfully in linux but when tried to run any function like pgdemo it gave the error

./pgdemo/:error while loading shared libraries libpgplot.so : cannot open shared object file : No such file or directory.

But I checked that this library is in the directory

What is the problem?

Comment: You don't have libpgplot.so just put it in your system and update /etc/ld.so.conf

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how you installed the library but be sure to run [ldconfig](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig) afterwards to setup the links. See this [other SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/167734/278836) for details.

> But I checked that this library is in the directory

You might want to be clear on this point. Which directory? Most systems look in `/usr/lib` for example.